# Should/does loose coupling also be applied between methods of the same class?

Tags: coupling

Assume class `A` with methods `M1` and `M2` has low coupling with other classes

a) Should we also make sure that each individual method in class `A` is not tightly coupled with any other method in the same class? Thus, should we make sure that changing code in `A.M1` doesn't also require us to change code in `A.M2`?

b) I assume if `A.M1` is performing two closely related tasks **T1** and **T2** instead of just a single task, then **T1** and **T2** are tightly coupled, since changes in `T1` may also require changes in `T2`?

thank you

Comment: From what I was taught, it's better to write methods that only perform one task each, even if they are closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write code that follows single-point-of-maintenance.  If you change something, only change it in one place.  This will reduce bugs throughout your code.  That being said avoid code duplication and split classes, methods, namespaces, etc. into parts parts with a single responsibility.

Changing something in method A() should not force you to make a change in method B().  Maybe use a helper function in both that shares common functionality.

EDIT: The SOLID acronym is a good one to follow for software design/engineering: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: hi, with regards to question b), are T1 and T2 tightly coupled?